# SHOUTcast streaming on Android

Tags: android, audio, streaming, shoutcast, internet-radio

How can I play a SHOUTcast stream on any Android version before 2.2?

Thanks!

Comment: Off the shelf software such as Stream Furious and Just Playlists handle this nicely.

Comment: How to play SHOUTcast?http://stackoverflow.com/a/8833346/265167